# Mypy and `None`

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Take the following function:

```py
from typing import Optional


def area_of_square(width: Optional[float] = None, 
                   height: Optional[float] = None) -> float:
    if width is None and height is None:
        raise ValueError('You have not specified a width or height')
    if width is not None and height is not None:
        raise ValueError('Please specify a width or height, not both')

    area = width**2 if width is not None else height**2
    return area
```

At the `area =` line, mypy complains that `height` could be None.

I could add the following line just above it:

```py
    height = typing.cast(int, height)
```

But that is not correct, since `height` could be `None`. Wrapping that cast in any sort of logic makes mypy get lost and I'm back to the error.

I personally use typing for readability and to avoid bugs. Getting errors like this (and often with lazy initialization and other similar uses of `None`) kind of defeats the purpose, so I like to fix them when it makes sense.

What are some strategies people use in this scenario?

Comment: The conditional is wrong. Prior to the calculation you are checking one of the two conditions: that BOTH width AND height are None and that BOTH width AND height are not None. But the case when height is None but width is None can still fall through. First conditional should be `if width is None or height is None:` and then mypy should stop complaining.

Comment: @pavel but that fall-through condition is exactly when the function executes...

Answer (score 3):

`mypy` cannot bind multiple variables with one common condition.

The following lines type guard both variables:

```
a is None and b is None
a is not None and b is not None
```

So they work as expected, while another condition:

```
a is not None or b is not None
```

is not informative for `mypy`, you cannot express "at least one of them is `not None`" and use it in type checking.

I'd do [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1e9024b0fa86c99594269ea50d43968b) instead:

```
from typing import Optional


def area_of_square(width: Optional[float] = None, 
                   height: Optional[float] = None) -> float:
    if width is not None and height is not None:
        raise ValueError('Please specify a width or height, not both')
    elif width is not None:
        area = width**2 
    elif height is not None:
        area = height**2
    else:
        raise ValueError('You have not specified a width or height')
    return area
```

Comment: I like this, though I do feel I put in a lot of effort changing code just go get mypy to understand it - this is a simple example, but I have these types of problems all over the place. I feel like adhering to mypy means making code less pythonic.

Comment: IMO your feeling is right. Without dymanic classes and metaclasses (yes, plugin system, but it is too much effort) things are harder, and stuff like this adds more inconveniences. That's why `mypy` is really useful mostly on large codebases, and tiny projects are more suffering from it. There is a lot of changes required just to satisfy `mypy`, which are opposite of concise and performant solutions. One of my "favorites" is replacing a comprehension with `append` loop with type `assert` for each element to make list of expected type.

Comment: This *is possible*, but currently, `mypy` doesn't support it: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6835